# How to allow other user to execute script on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I have script that works fine on my account but I want other user to be able to use that script over API Executable.

```
            var serviceScript = new ScriptService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = UserInfo.Credentials,
                ApplicationName = "Read Google Scripts .NET",
            });

            var scriptId = "scriptId";


            var Param = new { spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId };

            var exec = new ExecutionRequest();

            exec.Function = "createDocument";
            exec.DevMode = true;
            exec.Parameters = new List<object>();
            exec.Parameters.Add(Param);


            var script = serviceScript.Scripts.Run(exec, scriptId);


            
            //
            var result = script.Execute();
```

This is the error I got when other user tries to access:

`GoogleApiException: The service script has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. The caller does not have permission Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest<TResponse>.ParseResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)`

I am using OAuth 2.0 and after creating Apps Script I have two Client IDs

[image: gd console]

I have deployed script as 'Anyone with Google account' but it is not accessible over API and works fine as Web Application.

Comment: The question doesn't include enough details.

Comment: What details do you need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks it's only possible if I gave Editor role on script for everybody

Comment: What make you make this conclusion?

Comment: Do you have other conclusion?